# Add comma in number value

Tags: html, jsp, numbers, decimal

I have an integer value for example 1171906 and i want it to be display like this 1,171,906

Please give me some easy way in jsp code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

man, you are so lazy, but anyway, try this

```
System.out.println(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(1171906 ));
```

Comment: thanks, but i found it another way. using fmt format.
<fmt:formatNumber type="number" value="${number}" />